# Most appropriate statistical analysis for a 3 treatment, 3 period crossover design

Tags: crossover-study

I have a study looking at a particular blood measure after performing 3 activities (sitting (control), walking (intervention 1) and cycling (intervention 2). There will be a minimum wash out period between each trial and it will be randomised (15 participants). The primary aim is to look at whether the interventions have effect on this blood measure compared to control. Secondary aim will look at whether the interventions differ.

I am struggling to come to the conclusion of which statistical test would be appropriate. I may also need to consider covariates such as gender and age.

Comment: E.g. "Design and Analysis of Cross-Over Trials" by Jones and Kenward or Senn's "Cross-over Trials in Clinical Research" is a good text that should cover this reasonably nicely.